# Access VBA SQL where clause issue

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I need some help. When i run the below query I get no results back if i include the Pkg number part of the where. When i run the query in Access it works fine.
example of vars
package number 1_282 
Rptdt 201301

```
Dim db As Database 'generic database object
Dim rst As Recordset 'this is going to hold the query result
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim PKG As Double
Dim rptDT As Double
Dim wireDT As Date

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT Max(tbl_Revision.Revision_Number) as Revision_Number FROM tbl_Revision" & _
" where (tbl_Revision.RUN_YR_MO=" & rptDT & ")" & _
" and (tbl_Revision.Package_Number=" & PKG & ")")

getRevision = rst!Revision_Number + 1
```

Comment: what type tbl_Revision.Package_Number is ?

Comment: The package_number is a text field in the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PKG cant be a Double if you want 1_282 to work. So make it a string.
Also you will have to add quotes :

```
" where (tbl_Revision.RUN_YR_MO='" & rptDT & "')" & _
```

Comment: " and (tbl_Revision.Package_Number=" & PKG & ")")